# Upload file Scala Spray

Tags: scala, spray

Looking to create functionality to upload a file using multipart/form-data. However I cannot grasp how to change the MultipartFormData and store it in the file system. Below is what I have so far.

```
trait Service extends HttpService {

  private final lazy val fileWorker = actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props[FileServicesActor])


  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

    val demoRoute: Route = {
      path("file") {
          post {
            respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
              entity(as[MultipartFormData]) { formData =>
                uploadFile(formData)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }



  private def uploadFile(data: MultipartFormData)= {
    val response = (fileWorker ? UploadFile(data)).mapTo[Any].map { case t: Success => t
    case e: Error => Error.outputError(e)
    case _ => Failure(_)
    }.recover { case e: Exception => Failure(e)
    }
    complete(response)
  }

  }
```

The function resolves to this

```
  def uploadFile(data: MultipartFormData) = {

    val file = data.get("file")
    //not sure what to do with data here...
  }
```